# How do I set the background inside a <div> to an image

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem setting the background of a  container to a specific image my css for the container is as follows.

```
.info1 {
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundbox.jpg);
    border-style:double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #3f7171;
    width: 290px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

I have the container in html but everytime I save the file and view the webpage in browser it just sets the background of the container to Gray.

This is the  in the html file...

```
<div class="info1">

</div>
```

I have tried adding background-image to my css

```
background-image: url(../images/backgroundbox.jpg);
```

and also tried it using the full url path to the folder the image is in and also tried having it...

```
background-image: url('../images/backgroundbox.jpg');
```

and

```
background-image: url("../images/backgroundbox.jpg");
```

And again I always just get the  coming back with a gray background, and I just can't seem to put my finger on the problem, I feel like I may have done a silly mistake somewhere but just can't seem to spot it.

Comment: Try using just background: url("../images/backgroundbox.jpg");

Comment: Is your background image at good dimensions? Have you rerechecked the path to your image? The extension? Have you tried to display it somewhere else?

Comment: Just to get the obvious one out of the way - are you sure your URL is correct based on the images location from the webpage? Meaning you need the "../" ?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytG3L/) , did not make any changes to your code, Used a sample image url,

```
background-image: url('http://goodlogo.com/images/logos/hi_logo_2750.gif');
```

The problem seems to be in your image url , check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Since it requires 50 reputation to comment, I think I would have to make an answer and make it count.

It has to do with the file location.

Try to inspect the element, click on the Image Link within the console and see if you could find it. It would be also helpful if you can post the structure of your site here.

The code is correct, here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/5pBEv/).

```
.info1 {
    background-image: url("http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Ideal-landscape.jpg");
}
```

So the problem should be in "../images/backgroundbox.jpg". Make sure that the relative path is correct. Also, try to make sure that the div is visible (by having some content, specific width and height with display set to block or inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the url is correct, try adding `background-size: 100%`.
It might be just that the image is large and the gray is the top left area of that image.